# Is this Q&amp;A in the review section a bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, encoding

On my *Review* screen on StackOverflow, in the box to the right, I see the following text:

> ... Help your fellow members learn to use the site and raise the quality of Q&amp;A by ...

Is this programmer flair or an actual bug?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Seems we've had a couple of those recently.

Comment: "programmer flair"! What about runaway ampersand?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review) in build 2013.8.2.917 (sites) / 2013.8.2.1310 (meta)